# How to recover data in one kafka replica using the other two replica in 3 node kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 3 node kafka cluster. One of the replica's data got deleted. Is there a way we can recover the data by refering to the other 2 kafka nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka will automatically recover a replica if the topic is configured to have that a higher replication factor than that which is available.